Horizontal scroll overflow works only when vertical scroll overflow is not active
I'm trying to make a shiny app where the user can adjust the size of a plot, with scroll bars appearing when the plot gets too large for the page.
It works as desired when the vertical size is small enough that there is no vertical scrollbar. However, when the vertical size gets too large and a vertical scroll bar appears, the horizontal scrollbar goes away and the plot resizes itself horizontally to fit the page.
Here's a simplified version of what I have so far:
(I know the structure could be simplified to remove the renderUI/uiOuput pair in this simplified example, but it's not really possible in the full version).
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "My Chart",
  id = "my_chart",
  sidebar = 
    sidebar(
      width = 300,
      fluidRow(
        noUiSliderInput(
          inputId = "horizontal_zoom",
          label = "Horizonal zoom:",
          range =
            list(
              "min" = list(0.25),
              "50%" = list(1),
              "max" = list(4)
            ),
          min = 0.25,
          max = 4,
          value = 1,
          width = "200px",
          height = "18px",
          inline = TRUE
        ),
        
        
        noUiSliderInput(
          inputId = "vertical_zoom",
          label = "Vertical zoom:",
          range =
            list(
              "min" = list(0.25),
              "50%" = list(1),
              "max" = list(4)
            ),
          min = 0.25,
          max = 4,
          orientation = "vertical",
          value = 1,
          width = "10px",
          height = "200px",
          direction = "rtl",
          inline = TRUE
        )
      )
    ),
  nav_panel(
    title = "Here's another tab"
  ),
  nav_panel(
    title = "Here's the chart:",
    uiOutput(
      outputId = "trace_plot"
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) { 
  #Plot for Trace Explorer
  observe(
    {
      output$trace_plot <- 
        renderUI(
          div(
            style = 'overflow: scroll;',
            renderPlot(
              iris %>% 
                ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                           y = Sepal.Width)) +
                geom_point(),
              width = 1000 * 
                input$horizontal_zoom,
              height = 700 *
                input$vertical_zoom,
              res = 144
            )
          )
        )
    }
    
  )
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this?

Besides the scrolling issue your code has three issues conceptionally:

Don't put render functions in observers.
Your renderUI should return a plotOutput element and this should be filled by a corresponding renderPlot function. As a rule of thumb always couple *Output function with its corresponding render* functions.
width and height in renderPlot should either be auto, a number or a function.

Now to the problem at hand.
The sizing of a shiny plot can be indeed a bit tricky, as there are 2 places where the size can be defined: in the outer <div> controlled by plotOutput and the size of the rendered image controlled by renderPlot.
Then, one has to know some CSS rules to understand which size the final plot has. As always there are a couple of solutions and which one to chose depends on your requirements.
One way of dealing with it, is to define the plot as inline, which makes that the height and the width is totally controlled by the width and height parameters of renderPlot (the brethren from plotOutput have no effect in this case).
Secondly you should be careful to make sure that the surrounding div has a defined height otherwise, by CSS rules, it will automatically take the height of its content and the scrollbars you see are the ones from the body and not from the div (try it out and remove overflow altogether and you will see that there are still scrollbars).
Here's how I'd rewrite your server function:
server <- function(input, output) { 
  #Plot for Trace Explorer
  output$trace_plot <- 
    renderUI(
      div(
        style = 'overflow: scroll; height: 90vh;',
        plotOutput("plt", inline = TRUE),
      )
    )
  
  output$plt <- renderPlot({
    iris %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                 y = Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()
    },
    width = function() 
      1000 * input$horizontal_zoom,
    height = function()
      700 * input$vertical_zoom,
    res = 144
  )
  
}


Thank you, that works great! I appreciate the other feedback too, I'm new to shiny and this gives me some ideas about how to improve other parts of the script not included in the simplified version.

I tried, but I unfortunately don't have enough reputation to upvote answers! I've only posted on here a couple of times.
